# Why validation is not working?

Tags: forms, angular, validation

**corporate.html**

```
          <form #f="ngForm" name="corporateProfileForm" ng-submit="corporateFrmSave(objDS, objDSCurrency)" novalidate="">
             <div class="row  form-group">
               <div class="col-md-12" >                                                      
                  <input type="text" *ngIf="formData"  [(ngModel)]="formData.Corporate_Id"  id="corpid" title="Corporate ID" tab-index="1" name="corpid" maxlength="20"  #corpid="ngModel"  required/>
                 <label for="corp"><b>Corporate ID</b></label>
                 <div *ngIf="corpid.invalid && (corpid.dirty || corpid.touched)"  class="alert alert-danger">
                  <div *ngIf="corpid.errors.required">
                       Name is required.
                   </div>
                   <div *ngIf="ncorpidame.errors.minlength">
                       Name must be at least 4 characters long.
                   </div>
                   <div *ngIf="corpid.errors.forbiddenName">
                       Name cannot be Bob.
                   </div>

                  </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
           </form>
```

Iam getting error message as

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined

Comment: Difficult to find with just HTML code, post your scripts too

Comment: hey, did any of the answers help you? :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you define your variable with this structure:

> TS file

```
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  myform: any;
  corpid: FormControl;

  constructor() {

   }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.createFormControls();
    this.createForm();
  }

  createFormControls() {
    this.corpid= new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  }

  createForm() {
    this.myform = new FormGroup({
      corpid: this.corpid,
    });
  }
```

> HTML file

```
<div class="md-form form-sm form-group"
     [ngClass]="{
     'invalid': corpid.invalid && (corpid.dirty || corpid.touched),
     'valid': corpid.valid && (corpid.dirty || corpid.touched)
     }">
<i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i>
<input 
    type="text" id="corpid" class="form-control"
    required
    [formControlName]="'corpid'">
    <label for="corpid" class="">Your corpid</label>
</div>

<div class="form-control-feedback"
     *ngIf="corpid.errors && (corpid.dirty || corpid.touched)">
  <p *ngIf="corpid.errors.required">corpid is required</p>
</div>
```

It's hard to tell because issue is not in your HTML snipped but in `.ts` file.
I hope my Code will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `*ngIf`, so when that condition is checked, Angular renders the rest of the template, and while the small fraction of time while `*ngIf` is being evaluated, your template reference variable `corpid` does not exist, so it will throw an error when trying to check the validation intially.

Wrap the input field **with** the validation div's inside the `*ngIf` instead of applying it only on the input field.

```html
<div class="row  form-group" *ngIf="formData">
  <input [(ngModel)]="formData.Corporate_Id" id="corpid" ... >
  <!-- more code here... -->
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hm5nva?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**